# Why JQuery taking time to get load?

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery code where i am adding class to a pre-existing divs and this is taking much time to get load. Can anyone help in this so that it takes less time to get load:

```
var cnt = jQuery("tbody td").length;

for(var i=0; i<cnt; i++){
    var ct=("cls"+parseInt(i+1, 10));
    jQuery("tbody td:eq("+i+")").addClass(ct);

    for(var j=0;j<=1;j++)
    {
        $ ('#tab-1, #tab-2, #tab-3').find(".cls"+i+" .tableCell-inner div").eq(j).addClass("xxx"+i+j);

    }
}
```

I have tried it using set timeout function as well but of no use.

Comment: If this small piece of code is taking a long time to execute, then there is another problem, unless you have like a huge amount of `td`. It would be helpful if you provide us with information like: How many `td's` you have? What version of `jQuery` are you using? Where are you loading the `jQuery` from`?

Comment: Although note that you can improve the performance massively by putting a common class on all the `.tableCell-inner div` elements you're trying to target

Comment: Basically this is a dashboard and there are 3 tabs each tab containing table with some counts and there percentages corresponding to a particular product and i have provided classes to each td so i got approx 13000 tds overall in 3 tables. The above mentioned function is providing classes to those tds and it is taking time. So execution time for providing classes to those 13000 tds is taking time. Can we reduce this time so that classes can be provided in less time to those tds ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope we can't provide common class, each class has to be unique, since i need to perform some append function and static numbers to those unique classes.

Comment: So add 1 unique class and 1 common one...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually i need each unique class for td because i need to append uniuqe numbers corresponding to those classed using arrays and loops. But this adding of classed to 13000 tds is getting lot of time to get execute since there is addition of 13000 classes to tds. Any suggestions?

Comment: In that case use DOM traversal to find the elements you need as incremental classes or IDs are an anti pattern. If you need help doing that I'd suggest starting a new question with a full example of your HTML and JavaScript